# Sum sick leaves by month

Tags: sql, sql-server

Employees take sick leaves by date range. So they have range set as follow.

[image: Employees Sick Leaves]

I would like the data to be displayed as follow.

[image: Result should look like this]

I was able to think of query as follow but not sure how to modify it to get data as I shared.

```
SELECT MONTH(t.FromDate) AS [Month], FORMAT(t.FromDate, 'MMM') AS [MonthName],
       SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY,t.FromDate,t.ToDate)+1) AS [AbsenceCount] 
FROM Test AS t
GROUP BY FORMAT(t.FromDate, 'MMM'), MONTH(t.FromDate)
ORDER BY MONTH(t.FromDate)
```

Comment: which db you are using ??

Comment: No need to separate years from each other?

Comment: @scaisEdge SQL Server 2017.

Comment: @jarlh Yes! They will need to be separated.

Comment: Then you need to add `YEAR()` to your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A range of dates can be built using a CTE, then you can JOIN your absences to the dates that fall within the absence rang.  Then simply count these dates, and group by the year and month of the date.

I found out how to change your month number into text.  you could take LEFT(...,3) of that if you wanted.

```
WITH  DATRANGE AS (SELECT MIN((FromDate)) as startDate, max(ToDate) endDate From Test),
      YourCal AS (SELECT startDate d FROM DATRANGE 
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATEADD(day,1,d) d FROM YourCal, DATRANGE WHERE d < enddate
                 )
        SELECT T.empid, 
                YEAR(Y.d), 
                DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(y.d)-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime))) As M,
                COUNT(1) As DayCount 
                        FROM TEST T JOIN 
                                    YourCal Y 
                                            ON Y.d BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate
        GROUP BY T.empid,YEAR(Y.d),DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(y.d)-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime))),MONTH(y.d)
        ORDER BY empid, YEAR(y.d), MONTH(y.d)
        option (maxrecursion 0);
```

with 3 letter month tags, it will be

```
WITH  DATRANGE AS (SELECT MIN((FromDate)) as startDate, max(ToDate) endDate From Test),
      YourCal AS (SELECT startDate d FROM DATRANGE 
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATEADD(day,1,d) d FROM YourCal, DATRANGE WHERE d < enddate
                 )
        SELECT T.empid, 
                YEAR(Y.d) Yr, 
                LEFT(DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(y.d)-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime))),3) As M,
                COUNT(1) As DayCount 
                        FROM TEST T JOIN 
                                    YourCal Y 
                                            ON Y.d BETWEEN FromDate AND ToDate
        GROUP BY T.empid,
                YEAR(Y.d),
                LEFT(DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, MONTH(y.d)-1, CAST('2008-01-01' AS datetime))),3),
                MONTH(y.d)
        ORDER BY empid, YEAR(y.d), MONTH(y.d)
        option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I see is to join with a `calendar` table that contains all dates. You have to figure out for yourself how you want to create that table. I typically generate that in a php script.

```sql
select month(c.date)
,      count(*)
from calendar c
join test t on c.date >= t.FromDate 
            and c.date <= t.ToDate
group by month(c.date)
```

Comment: Tip: Use a recursive cte to create a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
: Use this query to solve your use-case (runs for MySQL, before the DB name was specified in the question):

```
CREATE TABLE Calendar_Table(
  dt DATE
);

INSERT INTO Calendar_Table VALUES
("2019-01-01"), ("2019-01-02"), ("2019-01-03"), ...

CREATE TABLE Sick_Leave (
  EmpId INT,
  FromDate DATE,
  ToDate DATE
);

INSERT INTO Sick_Leave VALUES
(1, "2019-01-01", "2019-01-31"),
(2, "2019-02-01", "2019-02-28"),
(3, "2019-03-01", "2019-05-01");

SELECT 
    x.month, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        a.EmpID,
        b.dt AS FromDate,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.dt, "-", 2) AS month
    FROM
        Sick_Leave a 
    JOIN 
        Calendar_Table b
    WHERE (b.dt BETWEEN a.FromDate AND a.ToDate)
) x 
GROUP BY 
    x.month;
```

You can refer to this SQLFiddle [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ebafe/5) for the solution. : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0ebafe/5

[image]

You could however, use one more calculation from either `case statements` or `another lookup table` to convert the result `2019-01` to `Jan`.

**For SQL Server**: This is the [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8dae7/6) for SQL Server DB: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8dae7/6